# jQuery - Get ID of element being removed

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following to remove a group of textboxes and labels in a "li" but I'd like to know the ID of any one of the elements in that group.  The solution to that might be enough for me to figure out the next step.

My next step: Each group of elements has a counter number assigned to it (e.g. textbox1 and label1 are in one grouping, then textbox2 and label2 in another).  If the second group of elements are removed, I want to know the id of at least one of the elements so I can rename all the elements in the next group with "2" instead of letting them remain with "3" and continue doing that with the rest of the groups of elements so there is no gap in the sequence unless there is a better way to "shift" the assigned numbers with a simpler method.

```
$("<a>CLICK HERE TO REMOVE THIS ENTRY</a>").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("li").remove();
}).appendTo(li);
```

Comment: You can not get the element that is removed. You may just hide those elements with hide() instead of remove(). Or maybe you can define a variable and follow your changes on that variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could assign a class to your textboxes, e.g. `class="myTextBox"` and then do something like this:

```
var deletedId = $(this).closest("li").find('.myTextBox').attr('id');
$(this).closest("li").remove();

// ...then do your next steps using deletedId.
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Not sure I understand why it was necessary to create the class.  Wasn't sure where to put it, but I figured it out.  After your suggestion, I first tried it by doing a find for the name of the element, but that didn't work whereas your suggestion to add the class did work. Looks like I have a lot more to learn.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.attr('id')` to get the id of the elements before you remove them. Then store the id in the parent div's data attribute. So you can reference it later.
I would also use a selector with a class.

EX.

```
$("a.remove_link").click(function() {
    // Find and set the li
    var li = $(this).closest("li");
    // get the id
    var input_id = li.find('input[name="foo"]').attr('id');
    // Set the id as data in some_element, Might be the parent div or form
    $('.some_element').data('last_input_id', input_id);
    // Remove the element
    li.remove();
}).appendTo(li);
```

Hope this helps.